# SPARQL DATASET definition

Tags: sparql

Can anyone explain to me what this statement "Dataset(QuadPattern,μ,GS,GS)" means?Especially, I am trying to figure out the model of DELETE DATA operation (DELETE DATA  QuadData) , but I cant understand what Dataset(QuadPattern,{},GS,GS) means.

Comment: If user205512's answer answered your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to let other users know that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be referring to the [SPARQL 1.1 Update spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#def_datasetQuadPattern):

> **Dataset(QuadPattern,μ,DS,GS)** ...[an] auxiliary function constructs an RDF Dataset from a QuadPattern, given a solution mapping and an RDF Dataset.

Put simply it's function which takes a bunch of RDF in graphs which may include variables, e.g.:

```
GRAPH ?g { ?person a Person ; ex:tel ?tel }
{ ?g ex:source ?source }
```

and a set of solutions μ:

```
{ ?g => <http://example.com/graph1> , ?person => <http://example.com/alice> , ?tel => "0898 505050" , ?source => <http://192.com/> }
{ ?g => <http://example.com/graph2> , ?person => <http://example.com/bob> , ?tel => "117 117" , ?source => <http://192.com/> }
```

and binds those values, resulting in a dataset:

```
{ 
  <http://example.com/graph1> ex:source <http://192.com/> .
  <http://example.com/graph2> ex:source <http://192.com/> .
}
GRAPH <http://example.com/graph1> { <http://example.com/alice> a Person ; ex:tel "0898 505050" }
GRAPH <http://example.com/graph2> { <http://example.com/bob> a Person ; ex:tel "117 117" }
```

Comment: So when we have μ = {} that means we have no values to bind or we bind all values? Actually the problem here is the definition of the empty solution mapping

Comment: In that case you'll get an empty dataset: no valid triples will be produced, and no valid graph names either. If you're used to the way `CONSTRUCT` works, then this is essential the same.